# Change multiple span values with select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change multiple span values based on the value of a select box. See my code below.

HTML:

```
<select id="selectCountry">
  <option value="0">Netherlands</option>
  <option value="1">Germany</option>
  <option value="2">Switzerland</option>
</select>
```

Javascript/jQuery

```
var addressData = [{"addressName": "Spiegelhof", 
          "addressStreet": "Herengracht 466", 
          "addressCity": "1017 CA Amsterdam", 
          "addressCountry": "the Netherlands", 
          "countryOne": "Netherlands", 
          "countryTwo": "Belgium", 
          "phoneOne": "+31 20 658 9800",
          "phoneTwo": "+32 2 588 12 77",
          "code": "NL"},
         {"addressName": " ", 
          "addressStreet": " ", 
          "addressCity": "Munchen", 
          "addressCountry": "Deutschland", 
          "countryOne": "Germany", 
          "countryTwo": "Switzerland", 
          "phoneOne": " ",
          "phoneTwo": " ",
          "code": "DE"}];


$(document).ready(function() {
$("#selectCountry").change(function() { 
    var value = $('#selectCountry').val();
    $('#addressName').html($(this).addressData[value].addressName);
    $('#addressStreet').html($(this).addressData[value].addressStreet);
    $('#addressCity').html($(this).addressData[value].addressCity);
    $('#addressCountry').html($(this).addressData[value].addressCountry);
}).change();
});
```

My console sais the he cannot read the property of [value] of undefined. Is my JSON data not correct? Should it be parsed and if so, how? Or does anyone know another solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example addressData is an array in the global scope, not a property of the jquery element $(this). Try this:

```
$('#addressName').html(addressData[value].addressName);
$('#addressStreet').html(addressData[value].addressStreet);
$('#addressCity').html(addressData[value].addressCity);
$('#addressCountry').html(addressData[value].addressCountry);
```

Comment: Wauw, I should've seen that earlier. Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `$(this)` to read `addressData` as `$(this)` refers to `selectCountry` select box, remove it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#selectCountry").change(function() { 
    var value = $('#selectCountry').val();
    $('#addressName').html(addressData[value].addressName);
    $('#addressStreet').html(addressData[value].addressStreet);
    $('#addressCity').html(addressData[value].addressCity);
    $('#addressCountry').html(addressData[value].addressCountry);
}).change();
});
```

Comment: Wauw, I should've seen that earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `$(this)` when you are setting the html content of the `span` elements. It should look something like this:

```
$('#addressName').html(addressData[value].addressName);
```

Comment: Wauw, I should've seen that earlier. Thanks for the quick reply!